# How to retrieve the data from different table on plsql and how to create report as xl file

Tags: plsql

I want to prepare a report in xl file in qa.In application there have some columns and records.i  want to combine all the data in backend to prepare a report on plsql.

Which query i will write to combine all the data in one report.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.